# How can I generate the board in a cleaner way?

Tags: javascript

So, I am writing a Tic Tac Toe game using native HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I've written a class for the board that looks pretty neat, which you can see below.

```js
class Board {
    #boardSize;
    #player1Symbol;
    #player2Symbol;

    constructor(boardSize = 3, player1Symbol = 'X', player2Symbol = 'O') {
        this.#boardSize = boardSize;
        this.#player1Symbol = player1Symbol;
        this.#player2Symbol = player2Symbol;
    }

    get boardSize() { return this.#boardSize; }
    get player1Symbol() { return this.#player1Symbol; }
    get player2Symbol() { return this.#player2Symbol; }
}

let board = new Board(3, 'X', 'O');
```

But I have another script that is responsible for generating the board into the HTML.

```js
let game_ui = document.querySelector('.game-ui');

let uiHTML = '';
for (let x = 0; x < board.boardSize; x++) {
    uiHTML += `<div class="row-${x}">`;
    for (let y = 0; y < board.boardSize; y++) uiHTML += `<input type="button" class="" id="btn-${x}.${y}" value=" " />`;
    uiHTML += `</div>`;
}

game_ui.innerHTML = uiHTML;
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="game-ui">
    </div>
</body>
```

My question is, is there a better way to write the `BoardGenerator` script? The class looks neat but the generator source code doesn't look all that good and is hard to read. How can I make my code more beautiful here? I know this is a bad question to ask, but still, I am curious on how I can improve the beauty of my code here.

Comment: By "generator" you mean  the  `for` loop that generates the html?

Comment: maybe you could compare the use of `document.createElement()` vs. string building https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878281/adding-elements-as-a-string-vs-createelement

Comment: For me this looks ok. But you should add the method to your board class as a function and call it directly in the boards constructor. Also you should not call the new Board in the board class file itself but in the main file which is importing the board file